# Are 2 process.nextTicks run on the same tick (aka frame)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Look at the following code:

```js
console.log("a")
process.nextTick(()=> console.log("b"));
process.nextTick(()=> console.log("c"));
```

This will of course print `a`, and then `b`, then `c`. `a` is written from a different frame (tick) than `b` and `c`, but are `b` and `c` written from the same frame?

so is it like this:

- frame 1: write `a`
- frame 2: write `b`, write `c`

or is is like this:

- frame 1: write `a`
- frame 2: write `b`
- frame 3: write `c`

Thanks!

Comment: Not an expert in node, but I always thought `nextTick()` callback was executed at the end of the same frame, whereas `setImmediate()` is executed at the beginning. So that would make "frame 1: write `a`, write `b`, write `c`", and your first list being the result of `setImmediate` and the second one of a recursive `setImmediate`.

Answer (score 2):

at the first look at this code:

```
let racer = function() {
  setTimeout(() => console.log("timeout"), 0);
  setImmediate(() => console.log("immediate"));
  process.nextTick(() => console.log("nextTick"));
  console.log("current event loop");
}

racer()
```

and out put is:

```
[Running] node "/Users/logicmason/timeouts.js"
current event loop
nextTick
timeout
immediate

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.203 seconds
```

- The first one executed was process.nextTick, which puts its callback at the front of the event queue. It will execute after the code currently being executed but before any I/O events or timers.
- Next is "timeout". Since we passed setTimeout a timeout of 0, there's no additional enforced delay before its execution, and it is placed on into the timer queue during the next loop.
- Finally, we have setImmediate, which is clearly not as immediate as its name suggests! Its callback is placed in the check queue of the next cycle of the event loop. Since the check queue occurs later than the timer queue, setImmediate will be slower than setTimeout 0.

All in all, the event loop looks like this:

**timers -> IO -> poll -> check ->close -> timers -> ...**

- Timers: callbacks from setInterval or setTimeout
- IO callbacks: callbacks from I/O events
- Idle: used internally by Node between IO and Poll phases
- Poll: retrieve new I/O events
- Check: callbacks from setImmediate execute here
- Close: handle closed connections like sockets

**it challenge Time** :)

```
let racer1 = function() {
    setTimeout(() => console.log("timeout"), 0);
    setImmediate(() => console.log("immediate"));
    process.nextTick(() => console.log("nextTick1"));
    process.nextTick(() => console.log("nextTick2"));
  }

  let racer2 = function() {
    process.nextTick(() => console.log("nextTick"));
    setTimeout(() => console.log("timeout"), 0);
    setImmediate(() => console.log("immediate"));
  }

  let racer3 = function() {
    setImmediate(() => console.log("immediate"));
    process.nextTick(() => console.log("nextTick"));
    setTimeout(() => console.log("timeout"), 0);
  }

  racer1()
  racer2()
  racer3()
```